# Alien Like Parallax Background

Tags: effects, style, graphic-styles, generate-image-assets

I have recently watched an episode of Rick an Morty. And one scene in particular really caught my attention:

[image: This Scene from the main cover]

It made me feel really special in a certain way. That there is so much more complexity and randomness out there than we can think of.
I now eanted to create a similar styled graphic for a personal project, and I want to know ehat I can do to simulate the feeling I have when looking at this scene.

My project is a small game where you can run around random planets in the galaxy(in 2d) and every planet should have a different feel.

Now I know how I could achieve something like this with layers:

[image: Procedural Parallax Background]

However It just doesnt feel the same. Also it feels like its is’nt to powerful, because all you can do is change the color scheme and manipulate the mountains. And I am afraid that it it will get old really quick.

What can I do to create this special feeling if complexity and beauty that is out there?

Comment: Draw by hand... digitally or on paper. That equals "randomness".

Comment: This is *quite* a broad question and not really well suited for StackExchange.

Comment: Your example is very flat and has no feeling of perspective and lacking in colour and detail - try creating a scene like the Rick and Morty example provided with discernible organic shapes. Maybe smoke a joint before you start.

Comment: "all you can do is..." It's your game, you can do whatever you want! I don't get what's the problem here.

Comment: Not sure I understand this question at all. Are you asking how to draw something that looks like the first example image? If so, I don't think this is answerable except to say, learn how to draw.

Answer (score 2):

The R&M scene is is intended to catch our attention and it succeeds. It depicts an imaginary world that is alive and full of interesting details.

By comparison, your desert scene looks dead. Nothing is happening. There's nothing especially interesting going on. Many of us can draw well and know numerous technical software tricks which can help, but if the passion is missing, the results will not be inspired. That's why I'm not a well known artist, only a 287001 in one website.

If you want to be something more, find some art or live subjects for inspiration, and use your imagination to invent your own scene. Begin by making sketches, preferably using pen and paper. Playing with a computer only wastes time, so open the computer only when you have something which can be refined. Computers and software alone will not create something unique. You must learn to be inventive.

Comment: It can be as is. Thanks again.